# opencv showing multiple image

Tags: opencv, python

I'm going to show continuous image in a single folder  and make it looks like a video

```
for img in glob.glob(path):
   image = cv2.imread(img)
   cv2.imshow('image',image)
   cv2.waitkey(100)
```

But it returns an error
(-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'imshow'.

what should I modify?

Comment: Modify your code so it shows which modules you import, else it will not run. Modify your code so it shows the value of `path`. And finally modify your question so it shows the names of the files you expect `glob` to find.

Comment: Of course I imported something, I tried showing single image successfully.
btw I fixed the problem now, thx

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to print out "img" variable? I believe it is something like a list of string such as "pic.png".
Instead of providing name of files, you should provide full directory path as following sample. Which I provided name_of_directory + name_of_files.

Ultimately, imread following string "C:\Users\Harri\source\repos\WebCam\WebCam\folder\pic.png", instead of merely "pic.png".

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
directory = r'C:\Users\Harri\source\repos\WebCam\WebCam\folder'
files = [directory + '\\' + f for f in os.listdir(r'C:\Users\Harri\source\repos\WebCam\WebCam\folder')]

for f in files:
    print(f)
    image = cv2.imread(f)
    cv2.imshow('Frame', image)
    cv2.waitKey(100)
```